Did are/a/ano evolve from kare/ka/kano?
In answer another question of mine regarding Old Japanese pronouns, user Arfrever made an interesting claim:

Coincidentally, kare and kanozyo personal pronouns in Modern Japanese have also developed from distal demonstrative pronouns, which lost initial k in many forms:
kare → are
kano → ano
kanata → anata

Another place where this claim is echoed is the Wiktionary entry for あ.

Etymology 5
/ka/ → /a/
Shift in pronunciation from か (ka). Appears from the Heian period.2

The only citation for this claim is from the 国語大辞典（新装版）. I don't have access to this dictionary, but the way it's cited here suggests it only supports the second sentence, "Appears from the Heian period.", rather than the first, "Shift in pronunciation from か (ka)." In fact, under the entry あれ【彼】 in the 日本国語大辞典（精選版）, there is indeed a claim that it "appeared from the Heian period", but nothing on whether it "shifted from ka" or not.

（１）古くは「これ」対「かれ」、「こなた」対「かなた」のように、近称「こ」対遠称「か」の対立が中心的であった。平安時代に「あ」「あれ」が現われ、しばらくは「か」「かれ」と共存して、おおむね、「あ」「あれ」は現場にない対象、「か」「かれ」は現場に見える対象のように使い分けられていたものと考えられる。中世に入ってしだいに「か」「かれ」が衰退し、遠称はもっぱら「あ」「あれ」が担当することとなった。

So did are/a/ano really "develop" or "shift" from kare/ka/kano? Needless to say but a credible source would be appreciated.

No time for a full answer, but if you look at the 「彼の語誌」 notes in the NKD entry here, you'll see that the か～ terms and the あ～ terms were used alongside each other, in slightly different use cases. This suggests that the あ～ terms were independent in origin, and not just phonological shifts from the か～ terms.

@EiríkrÚtlendi However in Old Japanese (8th century) there was already first-person pronoun a / are. It did not survive into Early Middle Japanese. a (but not are) is attested in Old Ryukyuan and maybe some modern Ryukyuan languages (Yonaguni, Miyako (Ogami, Irabu, Minna, and Nakasuji dialects), Okinawan (Sesoko dialect)).

@Arfrever I believe that that あれ is a variant of われ.

@broccoliforest Bjarke Frellesvig (2010, page 138) wrote: 「Among the 1st person forms, the a- forms are only used for exclusive, singular reference ('I, me (alone)'), whereas the wa- forms also are used for inclusive and plural reference ('me/us (including you)') and also reflexively ('myself, oneself'), suggesting that the wa- forms reflect an earlier indefinite personal pronoun 'one'. The wa- forms were used more than the a- forms and there is also some overlap in usage, indicating that a shift from a- to wa- as the 1st person pronoun was in the course of being completed;」

Alexander Vovin (2020, pages 216-218) has long discussion of various theories trying to link these pronouns (a- → wa- theory; wa- → a- theory), rejects them, and concludes with 「Yoshizō Itabashi was the first linguist who proposed to view wa- and a- forms as etymologically different (Itabashi 1999). Although I do not personally agree with his Austronesian etymology for a- forms (see section 2.2.2 below), I believe that his general proposal to separate the two forms genetically is probably a step in a right direction. …

… The crucial evidence that leads to the understanding of the difference between a- and wa- as well as to the reconstruction of the PJ situation comes from some South Ryukyuan languages, where a- is always singular ‘I’ and wa- is always plural ‘we.’ Thus, in this respect South Ryukyuan is more archaic than Old Japanese or any other variety of Japonic.」

@Arfrever A "shift" or "relationship" between wa and a isn't up for debate here because we have popular examples like watashi-atashi. What's less defensible is a supposed "shift" from ka to a. Unlike ki-to-i and ku-to-u shifts which have been systematically applied and recognized as onbin, there's no ka-to-a shift I'm aware of.

In this phonological context, neither /wa/ → /a/ nor /ka/ → /a/ was regular change, throughout all known history of Japanese. (Renjō process could have caused loss of non-initial /w/ in compound words, and /w/ of topic particle /wa/ (from earlier /pa/) and accusative particle ([wo] at that time).) atasi is much later, irregular, and word-specific formation.

If we assume that (1) OJ first-person personal pronoun a(re) is not etymon of EMJ distal demonstrative pronoun are, and (2) distal demonstrative pronoun kare is not etymon of EMJ distal demonstrative pronoun are, then it seems that there would be not enough time frame for a possible third etymology of EMJ distal demonstrative pronoun are.
